# Is it possible to check whether a String matches a String in an Array or Dictionary, Swift?

Tags: arrays, string, if-statement, dictionary, swift

Playing around with Swift here, and this might be a dumb question, but is it possible to check whether a String matches a String in an Array or Dictionary?

e.g

```
if string == array.String {
}

if string== dictionary.String {
}
```

I realize those examples are quite silly but just to show what I was thinking.
Thanks. :)

Comment: I cannot recognize from your "examples" what you are thinking. Do you want to check if an array contains a given string? Some concrete examples would be helpful.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I want to do. Sorry for the stupidity :P

Answer (score 1):

For arrays, you can use the `find()` function. It returns an optional `Int` which can be
tested against `nil`:

```
let array = [ "a", "b", "c"]
let searchTerm = "b"
let found = find(array, searchTerm) != nil
println(found)
```

This works with arbitrary arrays, not just with arrays of strings.

For a dictionary `dict`, the same method can be applied to `dict.keys` or `dict.values`,
depending on your requirements.